# index.js:1 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `active`

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-16

Does someone can say me what caused this error and how to fix it?
I already tried to change active keyword but still got same warning.
Not sure if it's problem with Styled components or with just attributes.
Down is the error and code.

[Actual error[image: Actual error]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7khgp.png)

26 row - div under return,
27 - , ...

Codeblock

```
 return (
    <div>
  <div className="App">
    <div className="portfolio__labels">
      <a
        href="/#"
        active={filter === "all"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("all")}
      >
        All
      </a>
      <a
        href="/#"
        active={filter === "frontend"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("frontend")}
      >
        Frontend
      </a>
      <a
        href="/#"
        active={filter === "mobile"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("mobile")}
      >
        Mobile
      </a>
      <a
        href="/#"
        active={filter === "ux-ui"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("ux-ui")}
      >
        UX/UI
      </a>
      <a
        href="/#"
        active={filter === "others"}
        onClick={() => setFilter("others")}
      >
        Others
      </a>
    </div>
    <div className="portfolio__container">
      {projects.map((item, key) =>
        item.filtered === true ? (
          <ProfileCard
            key={key}
            name={item.name}
            title={item.title}
            image={item.image}
            className="border-box"
            exerpt={item.exerpt}
            git={item.git}
            url={item.url}
            category={item.category}
            click="Push"
            sans-serif
            mb0-l
            mb3
            flex-none
            w5
            mr3
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you tag styled-components even if **theres no styled-components** in your code? What are you trying to achieve? There's no such prop as "active" on "a" tag. Just remove it.

Comment: @kinduser it was not all code. active choose all active items for the filtering.

Comment: I can barely understand what do you want to achieve here. Consider adding more details.

Comment: @kinduser https://medium.com/@lualmeida_90776/portfolio-filter-with-reactjs-and-react-hooks-b056f136bdba here was some way for portfolio filtering. I did the same just with adding map for project items.

Comment: But this `active` prop **does nothing**. Just remove it.

Comment: @kinduser right. You're correct. Thank you.